# Azure Application Insights REST API

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

Is there is any proper example to use Azure Application Insights REST API using the Azure API and Azure Active Directory ?

Comment: Not sure want you mean.

Comment: There are two methods are metioned int the api doc 1. API key authentication and 2. Azure Active Directory authentication but there is no example for the second method. i facing api rate limit issue with first method so i want to use second method

Comment: Can you provide me the link to that doc?

Comment: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits

Answer (score 2):

At the current time (2022) this information has all moved to Azure Docs, starting in this area:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/rest-api-walkthrough

Previous answer from 2017, now horribly out of date and dead links all over (thanks internet!):

<strike>There are examples of using both ways, API keys and Azure AAD at the top level page:</strike>

> ## Using the Public API format: API key authentication
>
> ```
> https://api.applicationinsights.io/{api-version}/{app-id}/{query-path}?[query-parameters]
> ```
>
> https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-authentication
>
> #Using the Azure API format: user authentication
>
> If you are using the [Azure API format](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats), then the authorization is
> done by [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/). You can learn more about specific
> [AAD authentication scenarios](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/) if you are using this to do per-user
> authentication.
>
> A useful resource for how to use AAD authentication is the
> [Developer's Guide to Auth with Azure Resource Manager API](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/05/23/developers-guide-to-auth-with-azure-resource-manager-api/), and
> this site also has a [useful set of PowerShell cmdlets](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/01/31/powershell-client-azure-resource-manager/) to handle
> the details of authenticating against AAD and sending an API call via
> ARM. They are a quick way to get a targeted set of Fiddler sessions
> showing the actual calls to authenticate and call our APIs via ARM (vs
> API keys direct to the API).

> For example, this sequence of PowerShell commands would run an
> [Analytics query](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Query) and dump out the JSON response:
>
> ```
> Connect-ARM
> Execute-ARMQuery -SubscriptionId {subscription-id} -HTTPVerb GET -Base "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourcegroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.insights/components/{ai-component-name}/api/query" -APIVersion "2014-12-01-preview" -Query "&query=requests|count" | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
> ```

Comment: Can it be done by nodejs ? Can i test it with rest client like postman or something ?

Comment: Links are out of date.